# How Can I Update applicationhost.config file to Enable PUT & DELETE verb in IIS 7?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, iis-7, iis-express, put, http-delete

My ASP.NET Web API Project work fine for PUT & DELETE Operation of development PC On IIE Express Server Mode. But In Test Server those two verb does not work. I am also try with update the {user}\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config with add two verb PUT & DELETE. This Way work fine for my Development PC but not in Test Server.

```
<add name="ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" responseBufferLimit="0" />
```

I am not success. What's i am wrong. Please! any one specify me.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: What? Do you use IIS Express on the test server instead of full IIS?

Comment: My Test Server is full IIS (IIS 7). I Use IIS Express on my Development PC. But My Application Does Not Work for PUT & DELETE verb on Test Server. Can explain me whats i am wrong.

Comment: IIS 7 does not work with .NET Framework 4.x by default. Please run aspnet_regiis to manually registery ASP.NET 4 on IIS, and then you should see everything works.